# Shopping cart quantity count to show up after form is submitted

Tags: php, html, ajax, shopping-cart

I have code configured to count the quantity of items I have in my shopping cart to display in an area on my site that the customer can see how many items that they have in their cart. The problem I am having is if they click add to cart, when the form redirects the quantity does not show up right away at the redirect. It only starts showing up when they leave to go to the next page. I am wanting this to show up right when they click add to cart.

The way I have it structured is I have a file that is required to load at the top of my file in all of my pages. That is where the quantity count it stored.

```
//Shopping Cart Quantity Count

if(isset($_SESSION['shopping_cart']) && is_array($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])) {
    $totalquantity = 0;
    foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] AS $product) {
        $totalquantity = $totalquantity + $product['quantity'];
    }
}
 else {
   $totalquantity = 0;
}
```

I'm not sure if this can be done with Ajax or if it can be done through my existing php code. I do not know hardly anything about Ajax, but if that is the way to go then I will.

I'm looking to hear ideas and maybe a step in the right direction of how to execute this. To get a first hand look, the site I am working on is buyfarbest.com

Comment: Yep, Ajax's the way to go.

Comment: I'm guessing you modify session data after showing product counter

Comment: I'm always showing the quantity counter. When the form is submitted to add to cart, the session data is modified.